# Response is not being written after Response.End() when request departs from asp:multiview or ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I wrote a HttpModule to intercept, evaluate and authorize requests, checking if logged user has appropriate access to the url being requested, in a pretty old legacy system written in ASP.NET 2.0(Web pages, not Web app), whose customer does not want to port to a newer framework. Restrictions have been loaded and cached at login time.

Everything works fine, except when some page contains an `<asp:MultiView>` component or when there is a button that launch an ajax method. When one of these situations occur, and user doesn't have rights to access that url, an alert box pops up with an "Unknown error" message, that came from a `ThreadAbortException` thrown by `Response.End()` method.

The question is: Why does my "Unauthorized" message is being overwritten by "Unknown Error" from the exception, only on these two situations?

Is there a way of doing an Url Authorization system, using database and caching and without cluttering `Web.config` with roles like those older ASP.NET samples?

```
// My module init method.
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(context_PreRequestHandlerExecute);

    // PreRequestHandlerExecute is the first stage at ASP.NET Pipeline
    // where we could get a fulfilled Session variable
}

private void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
    HttpContext context = application.Context;

    // additional request filtering/validation/etc.

    LoggedUser user = (LoggedUser)application.Session["user"];

    string path = context.Request.Path;

    // more checks and rules...

    if (!checkUserAuthorization(path, user))
    {
        context.Response.Write("<script>alert('Unauthorized. Contact your manager.');</script>");
        context.Response.Write("<script>window.history.back();</script>");
        context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        context.Response.End();
    }
}
```

**EDIT: What I've already tried (with no goal):**

- `Response.OutputStream.Close();`
- `Response.Flush();`
- `HttpApplication.CompleteRequest();`

Comment: Just do not call `context.Response.End();` as it may adversely affect other parts of the pipeline. Let the framework handle the end of the response.

Comment: Thank you @Nkosi for your comment. How could I stop the request before reaching controllers/pages instead? I know that in newer versions of ASP.NET we could add a customized "Authorize" Attribute, but how could I accomplish that in ASP.NET 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Foreword**

After a lot of research, finally I got it. Considering ASP.NET 2.0, concerning AJAX operations, the project I'm working uses a Microsoft component called "Atlas", [which in turn got renamed to ASP.NET AJAX](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111705/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/062106-1.aspx). At the time this system was written, the developers used the beta ASP.NET AJAX (codename "Atlas") to address all ajax and partial rendering needs.

I needed to dig deeper in source code (thanks to Reflector), to understand and inspect from where does that "Unknown Error" comes.

Inside the Microsoft.Web.Atlas, there is a file named `Microsoft.Web.Resources.ScriptLibrary.*.Atlas.js` (where `*` could be `Debug` or `Release`) which is rendered at runtime through a `WebResource.axd` "proxy".

This javascript file have a bug, because it expects to ASP.NET request always return an `HTTP 200 (OK)` response code, which in my code it's not happening (I'm returning a `403 Forbidden` code at my module).

**Code**

From `Microsoft.Web.Resources.ScriptLibrary.*.Atlas.js` taken from `WebResource.axd`:

```
this._onFormSubmitCompleted = function(sender, eventArgs) {

    var isErrorMode = true;
    var errorNode;
    var delta;
    if (sender.get_statusCode() == 200) {
        delta = sender.get_xml();
        if (delta) {
            errorNode = delta.selectSingleNode("/delta/pageError");
            if (!errorNode) {
                isErrorMode = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isErrorMode) {
        if (errorNode) {
            pageErrorMessage = errorNode.attributes.getNamedItem('message').nodeValue;
        }
        else {
            pageErrorMessage = 'Unknown error';
        }
        this._enterErrorMode(pageErrorMessage);
        return;
    }
// Code continues.
}
```

From this code, we can see that since response code is not an `200 OK`, that `errorNode` variable won't be set, and this `if (errorNode)` statement will always be `false`.

In this case, I was left with two options: Always return `HTTP 200` and modify all pages that have an `<atlas:ScriptManager>` with and add an `ErrorTemplate` tag on each, or supersede that script with one that consider `non-HTTP 200` responses, loading it below `</form>` tag at the Master page.

There is a lot of tutorials on how to do a proper error handling when using ScriptManager and UpdatePanels (an official one [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398934.aspx)), by subscribing to the `AsyncPostBackError` event), but this beta version (Atlas) simply don't have this event.

Answer (score 0):

it's by design. you must ignore it and add a catch for that exception.

```
try {
   context.Response.End();
}
catch{}
```

Comment: Ok, but how could I override that default "unknown error" message with my custom message? Why this works outside `asp:MultiView`'s and not within?

Comment: I think that your answer is lacking technical details/documentation and do not cover the mentioned aspects of the question.